# Why does Blender 2.70 not stay in Orthographic view when rotating from, say, Front Ortho view?

Tags: 3d-view

I've just upgraded to 2.70 and now when I'm in Front Ortho view (or Back Ortho, Right Ortho, etc) and rotate out of it into User view, it switches out of Orthographic mode into Perspective. Blender 2.69 didn't do this? Why is it happening now in 2.70?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In blender 2.70 *Auto Perspective* is turned on be default in the user preferences. This will cause you to go from perspective to orthographic when changing from the User View a view like the side view. The same is true visa versa.

To change this behaviour you can edit the user preferences.

1. Open the user preferences, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>
2. In the *Interface* tab disable *Auto Perpective*
3. To make this change permanent *Save User Preferences*

[image]

Comment: You are my hero. This has been a constant nuisance chipping away at my insanity ever since I upgraded to 2.70, and finally I decided to come here to ask this exact question only to find it was already answered!

Comment: For the people coming to this page from the future: In Blender 4.0, this option is in Navigation > Orbit & Pan > Auto > Perspective