# Disable or change rotate view (into 3d workspace) when in orthographic 2d view

Tags: interface, 3d-view, workflow, customization, orthographic

In 3d workspace how to disable or change rotate view (into 3d workspace) when in orthographic 2d view ?

When you are in top, side, front, back, left, right or bottom view the view changes when you accidentally press the middle mouse button and move. It's not very helpful when the view changes. How can this mouse behavior be disabled only for the mentioned views, top, side, front, back, left, right or bottom view.

This solution is not completely OK because it does not allow for multiple 2d views.

[Move forward in orthographic view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40182/move-forward-in-orthographic-view)

(Although I have used it with a few downsides)

Don't know why but following solution doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe I did something wrong or overlooked something else. Using blender 2.78.

[Why does Blender 2.70 not stay in Orthographic view when rotating from, say, Front Ortho view?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7934/why-does-blender-2-70-not-stay-in-orthographic-view-when-rotating-from-say-fro)

Maybe stored views add on is a solution (it hot-keys are available) but right now it doesn't seem to work. (It used to before)

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/stored_views

Comment: Quad view (Ctrl+Alt+Q) in the viewport will lock MMB from changing the ortho view (unless you uncheck Lock in the Properties shelf), however it doesn't provide you with back, left and bottom views and will be present inside of one window editor. I don't think the MMB behaviour can be changed only for the orthographic projection.

Comment: I don't know how often you "accidentally" bump the middle mouse button, but if you hold **Shift** while dragging the middle mouse you can pan a view without rotating it. Other than that, Quad view is really the only way. There is currently no direct solution to "lock" a view. Except perhaps you can try this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/356/how-to-lock-the-view-to-prevent-rotation-of-the-view-camera

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

This ...

https://gist.github.com/Fweeb/bb61c15139bff338cb17

... is some help, better than nothing.

What is preferred is a different kind of key bind when in 2d view but this seems only limited to quad view. (As seems this is asked a few times before I'm not the only one)

Comment: Further more if someone wants to mimic the quad view behavior event more they can also install the add on 'Lock all views to active'. When multiple custom views are open you can dynamic aligned the view of all view ports to the 'related' selected object. When the object is moved all view ports keep the object in the center. When another object is viewed the dynamic aligned view have to be activated again by the add on.(Works with hot key)

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4923/can-i-lock-the-viewport-to-always-jump-to-what-is-currently-selected [mod. > call this thread closed]

Comment: Let me give some feedback:

Add on ´lockview'
 https://gist.github.com/Fweeb/bb61c15139bff338cb17

Is not helpful for me because it resets the remapped view hot keys.
Now, with custom set of hot keys and addon lockview installed, it is not possible to change the viewing method from top to side or something else. With this setup situation is worse than before.